Magical Robin Hood/Sherwood Forest novel series
I'm looking for a story that takes place in Sherwood forest. It was written by a female author, with a "two initials and surname" type of name.
There are at least two books in the series, and I think that the second book at least was published within the last five years.
I never read the first one, but the second one opens with two teenage characters, one male and one female, sitting in a tree, possibly talking about King Richard and the current state of things in England.
The male character lives in a monastery, and I remember a scene of him climbing over a wall to sneak back in.
Friar Tuck is also in the early chapters, living in a cave. I remember that magical, faery-type creatures are also in this setting along with the church elements.
I never got to finish the book, so don't remember what happens after this.

I feel like you probably would have mentioned it, but did it have a gay Robin who had a complicated relationship with Guy of Gisbourne?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48513180-shirewode is the closest I've found so far, but the second book doesn't open on two teenagers, Richard is mentioned offhand in the first few pages, and Tuck shows up near the end. Plus, I think you would have mentioned that Robin was gay and Marion his sister.

I think you might be talking about two books by Rachel Atwood called "Walk the Wild with me" (2019) and its sequel "Outcasts of the Wild Wood" (2022).
I have read the first one.  It is a Robin Hood pastiche complete with fae creatures and mostly set within a monastery.  The hero does indeed have to climb over the wall (to visit his sister if I recall correctly).  Friar Tuck does make several appearances.
I don't have the second book, but a search of its text with Google Books shows that the first time it mentions "King Richard" is on page 5.

Prince Arthur, like his Uncle King Richard, the lionhearted, loved war too much and women too little.  Ten years into John's reign he had alienated half his nobles.

It seems quite likely to be the book, even though the author is not identified with two initials.

That's definitely it, thank you! Not sure where I got the two initials from., although I think Rachel Atwood is just a pen name.
